# Zip attachment for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress.com

I noticed that there is no option to upload .zip files to wordpress.com. Lots of blog services give permission to their users for this. I'm a programmer and a lot of my blogs contain code samples. How can I attach my codes to my blogs?

Comment: Use a 3rd party service like gisthub or pastebin. There are plenty to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a free account at http://box.net or [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) to upload and share .zip files, but unless you have a LOT of code that you want to share, you're probably better off embedding your code samples into your posts.

Wordpress now supports [posting source code](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) on blogs hosted through their site:

> While WordPress.com doesn’t allow you to use potentially dangerous code on your blog, there is a way to post source code for viewing. We have created a shortcode you can wrap around source code that preserves its formatting and even provides syntax highlighting for certain languages [...]

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it's just needed to post the entire project. I previously used dropbox but I was looking for another solution.